# Is it good practice to lock a pthread mutex before destroying it?

Tags: c++, pthreads

```
class AAA
{
    ...
    ~AAA()
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock( &m_mutex );
        pthread_mutex_destroy( &m_mutex );
    }
}
```

Question> I saw this code somewhere in a project. Is it good practice to do so?
Or it is undefined behavior to lock a mutex before destroying it?

Comment: If you feel the need to lock it, it should imply that another thread could try to ask for it. What would happen to that thread when the mutex was destroyed?.

Comment: @JanPetterJetmundsen, I didn't write the code and need to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: It's undefined. @JanPetterJetmundsen is right. It's not a good practice to lock the mutex before destroy it, even though in most implementations it does not do anything wrong.

Comment: @Gabriel How can that other question be a duplicate if its answers seem to be the exact opposite of the ones provided below?

Comment: @JanPetterJetmundsen this code strikes me as _so preposterously bad_ that I'm (hoping) there's a reason.  I'd like to know what the person who actually wrote the code was thinking--this kind of apparent error takes _effort_.

Comment: @imallet "I want to destroy my mutex. But what if someone else tries to use it? Better make the destruction thread-safe. And what luck! I already have the perfect mutex for that."

Comment: Looking down the related questions list, I see a lot of people finding themselves in similar situations, where they want to destroy a mutex without truly being done with it. Sounds like a common mistake.

Answer (score 35):

It strikes me as utterly terrible practice.

from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html

It shall be safe to destroy an initialized mutex that is unlocked. Attempting to destroy a locked mutex results in undefined behavior.

so this code guarantees undefined behavior and needs to be fixed.

Comment: For completeness, the up-to-date man-page: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html

Comment: Also note that according to that man page, attempting to *lock* a *destroyed* mutex also results in undefined behavior. (If there's any reason to lock this mutex, that means another thread might try to lock it, too.)

Answer (score 6):

This [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) says its undefined behavior.

Maybe from where you saw this code, the original coder wanted to destroy the mutex and might have thought that if he/she would be able to lock that mutex, then that means it's unlocked somewhere else by some important thread, and thus he can delete it.

But it's implemented incorrectly.